# Replacing outlier removal from IQR to MAD

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, outliers, mad

A common outlier removal formula is `Q3 + IQR * 1.5 and Q1 - IQR * 1.5`

Outliers can also be removed using Mean Absolute Deviation and Median Absolute Deviation.

Is anyone aware of any rules of thumb around these two latter methods? Similar to how IQR is scaled to 1.5 and tends to work well on ***many*** distributions?

Comment: Outlier (let's better call them extreme values) detection is fine. Automated outlier removal is not recommended by statisticians. You'll find many posts about this topic, including some that suggest better practices.

Comment: We loosen the bounds above 1.5 and inspect what we can visually. When data is this large we have to do many things using logical assumptions.

Comment: _Automated_ outlier removal almost always results in loss of potentially useful information. Removal of an outlier _known_ to have resulted from data entry error or equipment failure is reasonable. Also, it makes sense to remove outliers that are obviously impossible (negative height measurement, 173 year old patient, etc.). But those also invite investigation of data integrity.

Comment: The same comment repeated is not stronger, but I add my voice to those of Roland and @BruceET. I don't agree at all with "works well on almost anything" and note further that the 1.5 IQR convention was never intended by J.W. Tukey, who used it as a criterion for separate display of points on box plots, as a criterion for outlier removal. The idea was the complete opposite, that such points are likely to be interesting and important and require thought, not automated removal.

Comment: FYI  @Roland as endorsement.

Comment: Idea of using MAD somehow for outlier _detection_ is interesting. But it would require some hard work looking at samples of various sizes from many different kinds of populations to get a MAD-based method that is accepted as more useful than the familiar boxplot IQR-based method. // About 1.5 IQR being optimal: For a while 3.0 IQR was popular for ident of 'probable' outliers, compared with 1.5 for 'possible' outliers. Seem to recall that 2.25 IQR was suggested for a while as giving aprx same % of outliers in samples of different sizes from normal pop's. Best or not, 1.5 IQR _is_ now most-used.

Comment: BruceET, Yes I think it's interesting too. It's becoming popular with distributions without variance or mean, Example: Cauchy distribution.

Comment: About 40% of our variables are low value Poisson count data. Some nested groups have equal values for quartile-1 and quartile-3, so IQR is zero. We impute a default quasi-IQR or outlier removal fails for that group. We have 800,000+ rows of data with 90+ variables and 3 levels of multi-labelled nested groups. We unfortunately don't have the resources to exhaustively investigate each outlier.

Comment: Interesting report which uses MAD for outliers. https://dipot.ulb.ac.be/dspace/bitstream/2013/139499/1/Leys_MAD_final-libre.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under some distributional assumption you could find a rule that would highlight as unusual a similar fraction of the distribution as that box plot rule does - at least in large samples.

E.g. For a normal distribution asymptotically 0.7% of the distribution is extreme by the box plot rule.

If you did median absolute deviation from the median 'MAD' as your spread and median as location, median + mad would be similar to Q3 and median - mad would be similar to Q1 (with a symmetric distribution), so median ± 4 mad should be like the boxplot bounds. The behaviour would be less similar with skewed distributions but may still be reasonable.

If you wanted some rule in terms of say mean and mean deviation or median and mean deviation you could set it so that in very large samples it also cut off about 0.7% of the distribution - but these would be more affected by outliers and less similar in behavior than the other two would be.

A simple calculation indicates that the large-sample equivalent cutoffs (at the normal) to the boxplot rule is about 3.38 mean deviations from the center (whether mean or median).

[image: Image is a boxplot for a very large sample from a normal distribution, and similar limits to boxplot whisker ends (at the normal) calculated using the other statistics being discussed]

The limits calculated each way there are very similar. However, if we choose a heavier tailed symmetric distribution, the one based on mean deviation from the mean will be wider. If we choose a skewed distribution, all three will tend to be somewhat different.

Comment: Thats very interesting. Thank you Glen.

Comment: If you have time, using the same methods a few Poisson count data distributions would be of great interest.

Answer (score 4):

Boxplot outliers (according to your 1.5 IQR rule) are *characteristic* of
many common distributions. For example, among normal samples of size 100,
there is on average about one boxplot outlier per sample, and over half
of such samples have at least one outlier.

```
nr.out=replicate(10^6,  length(boxplot.stats(rnorm(100))$out))
mean(nr.out)
[1] 0.924752
mean(nr.out > 0)
[1] 0.521987
```

Here are boxplots for 20 normal samples of size 100.

[image]

Same for samples of size 100 from an exponential population.

[image]